# Why do the LUT table images intermittently fail to load in GPUImage in ObjectiveC / iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, computer-vision, gpuimage

I made a *simple* trial app with the functionality of live previewing a few filters (color LUT tables). Frequently when the app launches, the LUT filter effect is not applied, or is applied with no discernible change. IF I close the app and re-launch until I see a change, it will eventually work as expected.

After discovering that it would eventually work and that I had not made a totally incorrect implementation of the GPUImage library, I began to think it was a load order or timing problem. I added a `UISegmentedControl` to change the source .png for the LUT filter to allow modifying the filter well after launching the app. To my dismay, if the LUT image loads incorrectly at launch, changing the LUT source image after the fact via the `UISegmentedControl` has no (observable) effect. At this point, I'm thinking that perhaps there is something more fundamental at play that I am not aware of yet.

Here is the view controller, where most of the relevant code is. Again, this was intended to be more of a proof of concept than a final product at this stage, but the concept is only intermittently proving, heh!

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "GPUImage/GPUImage.h"
@import CoreFoundation;
@import ImageIO;
@import UIKit;

@interface ViewController ()
- (void)applyColorLUT:(NSString *)LUTFileName;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 435)];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

    NSArray *filterTypeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *navSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:filterTypeArray];
    navSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height-50), self.view.frame.size.width, 50);

    [navSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(NavSegmentControlAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [navSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];


    filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height-50))];
    filteredVideoView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    filteredVideoView.fillMode = kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill;
    [self.view addSubview:filteredVideoView];
    [self.view addSubview:navSegmentedControl];

    //set up video capture/source
    videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = NO;
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = NO;



    lookupFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
    [self applyColorLUT:@"lookup_first"];

      //run
    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)NavSegmentControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:{
            [self applyColorLUT:@"lookup_first"];
            break;}
        case 1:{
            [self applyColorLUT:@"lookup_second"];
            break;}
        case 2:{
            [self applyColorLUT:@"lookup_third"];
            break;}

    }
}

- (void)applyColorLUT:(NSString *)LUTFileName
{
    [videoCamera removeAllTargets];
    [lookupImageSource removeAllTargets];
    [lookupFilter removeAllTargets];

    lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:LUTFileName]];
    [lookupImageSource processImage];
    [videoCamera addTarget:lookupFilter atTextureLocation:0];
    [lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter atTextureLocation:1];
    [lookupFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

}


@end
```